# 2 exercises: finding the limit and showing continuity and differentiability

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

part 1:

$$\lim _{x\to _{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}^{-\:\:}} }\left(tg\left(x\right)\right)^{\sin\left(2x\right)}$$
so if $$\lim _{x\to _{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}^{-\:\:}} }\left(tg\left(x\right)\right)^{\sin\left(2x\right)}=L$$ then $$\lim _{x\to _{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}^{-\:\:}} }\sin\left(2x\right)\cdot ln\left(tg\left(x\right)\right)=\ln\left(L\right)$$
then $$\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}^{-\:\:}}\left(\frac{\ln\left(tg\left(x\right)\right)}{\frac{1}{\sin\left(2x\right)}}\right)=\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}^-}\left(\frac{\frac{1}{tg\left(x\right)}\cdot \frac{1}{\cos^2\left(x\right)}}{-\frac{1}{\sin^2\left(2x\right)}\cdot \cos\left(2x\right)\cdot 2}\right)=\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}^-}\left(\frac{\cos\left(x\right)}{\sin\left(x\right)\cdot \cos^2\left(x\right)}\cdot \frac{\sin^2\left(2x\right)}{-2\cos\left(2x\right)}\right)=\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}^-}\left(\frac{\cos\left(x\right)}{\sin\left(x\right)\cdot \cos^2\left(x\right)}\cdot \frac{4\sin^2\left(x\right)\cos^2\left(2x\right)}{-2\cos\left(2x\right)}\right)=\frac{0}{1}=0$$

Therefore $\ln\left(L\right)=0;\:L=e^0=1$

*part 2:*
$$0\leq f\left(x\right)\leq \ln^2\left(1+x\right)$$
 1. Show that $f$ continious at $x=0$
 2. show that $f$ differentiable at $x=0$

First of all: $$x=0\:;\:0<=f\left(x\right)<=ln^2\left(1+0\right)=0$$ therefore $f(0)=0$. Now: $$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(0\right)<=\lim \:_{x\to \:0}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)<=\lim \:_{x\to \:0}\left(ln^2\left(1+0\right)\right)=0$$ Therefore as a result of the sendwich rule: $$\lim \:_{x\to \:0}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)=0$$

And we got $$\lim \:_{x\to \:0}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)=f\left(0\right)=0$$ There for it is continious.

Now lets look at the derivative by definiton: $$\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(0\right)}{x-0}$$

And we'll devide it to 2 cases: $x>0$ and $x<0$
$$$$If $x>0$ then $$\lim \:\:_{x\to \:\:0^+}0<=\lim \:_{x\to \:0^+}\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}<=\lim \:\:_{x\to \:\:0^+}\frac{ln^2\left(1+x\right)}{x}$$
Therefore $0<=\lim \:_{x\to \:0^+}\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}<=0$ and therefore $\lim \:_{x\to \:0^+}\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}=0$. Same thing with $x<0$ (only the inequality is opposite), and because of that it is differentiable at $x=0$ and $$f\:'\left(0\right)=0$$

Comment: Your limits in the first part seem wrong: $x \rightarrow x \rightarrow \frac{\pi^-}{2}$ is not a correct way to write that. Do you have any information about the function $g$? Is it continous?

Comment: For part 2 we can see that $f(0)$ is zero by the squeeze theorem, $ln^2(1+0)=0$ and $0 \leq f(0) \leq ln^2(1+0) = 0$.

Comment: tg(x) is shortcut for tan(x). It is a known shortcut, but not everybody use it. 
About the second part, continuity, yes, sqeeze theorem, that what I wrote, but called it sandwich theorem as we call it.

Comment: In the first, minor typo in expansion of $\sin^2(2x)$.

Comment: Andre, I didnt understand what do you mean? What do you want to tell me by that?

Comment: In general, it might have been better to post this as two separate questions, since they don't appear to be closely related.

Comment: Michael, you right, I will do it next questions. But do my calculations seemed to be right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do part 1: With the substitution $x=\arctan y,$ we can evaluate the limit as $y\to \infty.$ In terms of $y,$ we have $\tan x = y$ and

$$\sin 2x = 2 \cos x\sin x = 2\frac{1}{\sqrt {1+y^2}}\frac{y}{\sqrt {1+y^2}} = \frac{2y}{1+y^2}.$$

So our expression is

$$y^{2y/(y^2+1)} = (y^{1/y})^{2y^2/(1+y^2)}.$$

That $\lim_{y\to \infty} y^{1/y}= 1$ is well known, and the exponent $\to 2.$  The desired limit is therefore $1^2 = 1.$